# how to get url associated with a cookie in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I am using `chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(c){console.log(c);})` to get all the cookies stored on the system. However, if I need to process the resulting cookie to either delete or whatever, I need a URL associated with each cookie. The URL strangely is not in the cookie structure: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html#type-Cookie

Anyone know how to get the URL associated with a cookie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build the URL from the information you've got from `getAll()`:

```
var cookie; // one single cookie from the array

var url = '';
// get prefix, like https://www.
url += cookie.secure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
url += cookie.domain.charAt(0) == '.' ? 'www' : '';

// append domain and path
url += cookie.domain;
url += cookie.path;

console.log(url); // something like "https://www.stackoverflow.com/"
```

Comment: Now cookies also have domain in this format `".www.primevideo.com"` the above logic might fail for few cases in this condition `url += cookie.domain.charAt(0) == '.' ? 'www' : '';` Anyways, thank you for this answer

Answer (score 2):

The *domain* property gives you the domain associated with the cookie. And *path* gives you the path inside that domain. From the [Cookie API Test Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/cookies.zip):

```
function removeCookie(cookie) {
  var url = "http" + (cookie.secure ? "s" : "") + "://" + cookie.domain +
            cookie.path;
  chrome.cookies.remove({"url": url, "name": cookie.name});
}
```